Install peer dependencies in lib automatically on the client side
I am developing a React package/library and have compiled it using Rollup. The package includes several components that need to be used in an Angular app.
I've specified a few packages as peerDependencies in my library's package.json. However, when my package is installed, I want to ensure that these peer dependencies are also automatically installed for the client.
How can I enforce the installation of peer dependencies when my package is installed?
I couldn't find anything useful yet, there is a plugin install-peers but the client will have to run a command to install peers for that.

Packages, which the library itself depends on should be in dependencies and not in peerDependencies. This will also make sure that the packages are installed always.
According to the npm docs, peer dependencies should be used if "you want to express the compatibility of your package with a host tool or library, while not necessarily doing a require of this host".

Yes, but the problem is, I have multiple custom packages/libs, If i add npm packages to each package as dep, then i get error for multiple instances for some of the packages when i compiled them with rollup, it's an atomic design, where each lib is dependent on the other.

Did you found any solution for this ? please share it if yes :)
